# Consulta selectiva de solicitud de datos de un api json?

Tags: json, api, djangorestframework

Mas que una pregunta, es una consulta, actualmente estoy con una api sirviendo datos, y he llegado a la siguiente situación, tengo una tabla preferencias de usuario, donde se almacenan las opciones de configuración de cada usuario, con json, hago un get y me devuelve todos los datos de esa tabla, y luego me toca filtrar esos datos con el id de usuario que esta logeado, mi punto es, hay otra forma de hacer esto, es decir con mysql en la consulta ponía el id del usuario y solo me regresaba los datos de ese usuario, aca me carga los datos de todos los usuarios y luego me toca filtrar.
Como soy inexperto, temo que si tengo un registro con mas de mil datos, y al final solo necesite 1 de esos datos, me toca cargar todo eso, y al final afectaría el rendimiento de mi pagina.

Ya es muy tarde para echarme atrás con el api, me gustaría saber si hay solucion, o quizás estoy exagerando y esto no afecte el rendimiento.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como lo haces en MySQL así se hace en [djangorestframework](/questions/tagged/djangorestframework). Es mucho más fácil si usas modelos en tus [ViewSets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)

Si tienes un *ViewSet* para tu modelo `Usuario`:

```
class UsuarioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Usuario.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsUsuarioAdminOrReadOnly]
```

Solo tienes que agregar este a tus rutas:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'usuarios', UsuariosViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Y las [rutas](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) se generan automáticamente:

- Lista de usuarios: `^accounts/$`, se llama `'usuarios-list'`
- Detalle de usuarios: `^accounts/{pk}/$` y se llama `'usuarios-retail'`

Y tiene los verbos más comunes, `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` y `PATCH`, según los hayas configurado.

Te recomiendo que consultes la documentación del proyecto que es muy completa y que sigas las reglas de la guía [**Cómo hacer un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) al hacer tus preguntas.